# I burnt Ubuntu to a cd, and when I went to install it, it asked me to remove the cd and press enter. Then it booted into windows

Tags: installation

As you can see by the very long title, that's exactly what happened. After I proceeded to install Ubuntu (12.04 LTS) to my computer, making it run alongside Windows 7, I got a black screen asking me to remove the cd, close the disk tray, and press enter. Now I m back in Windows. Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Try holding Shift during boot-up.

If that doesn't work, then the GRUB bootloader is not installed.

You'll need to reboot into the Live CD, open up the Terminal (`CTRL` - `ALT` - `T`) and type the following commands:

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
sudo update-grub2 /dev/sda
```

If you run those commands successfully, and you're *still* booting straight into Windows, then reboot again and hold Shift while it's starting up.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will solve your problem, but give it a try.

In Windows, right-click **Computer** and go to **System Properties**->A**dvanced System Settings**.

Then go to **Startup and Recovery**.
Check the **Time to display list of operating systems** if not checked, and give it the number of desired seconds (30, for example). Just in case, set the **Default Operating System** to **Ubuntu**.

**NOTE:** The above steps are for Windows 7. It may vary for other versions.

Comment: This will help only if Windows bootloader is installed, which is not the case after Ubuntu installation.

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved in the following way

1. once prompted to remove dvd and close the tray and press enter, do it without any delay.
2. now your system starts with windows automatically, if not you start your system.
3. wait for all windows services to start.
4. now go to startup folder, you will find wubi there.
5. click on it and follow the instructions ubuntu gets installed.